# Using XPath in Jaspersoft Studio to compare field values to parent

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio to display 6 rpm and readings within a table. There are two datasets, one for the table itself and one for the 6 readings stated above. 
The issue I'm having is I need to group these 6 readings to each table by using their mudPropertiesUid values. Just to give you an idea, I'll show you a section of the XML document:

```
<root>
   <modules>
      <MudProperties>
         <mudPropertiesUid>
         <.....>
         <MudRheology>
         <MudRheology>
         <MudRheology>
         <MudRheology>
         <MudRheology>
         <MudRheology>
            <rpm>
            <reading>
            <mudPropertiesUid>
      <MudProperties>
         <....>
         <MudRheology> (x6)
```

As you can see, there are 6 MudRheology nodes for each MudProperties node, each having mudPropertiesUid within.

The Question:
Using the Jaspersoft Reports Dataset and Query dialog, I have the following which does not work:

```
/root/modules/MudProperties/MudProperties/MudRheology[mudPropertiesUid = parent::mudPropertiesUid]
```

What I'm trying to do is to display the 6 mudRheology rpm & reading if each MudRheology mudPropertiesUid is the same as the parent nodes mudPropertiesUid value.